# How to set class attributes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class-attributes

I have class attributes in my class, that I want to set dynamically, here's a code example

```
class Something:
     attribute1 = 42                 # this is shared between all class instances
     def _init_(self, value):
          self.value = value
```

my question is: Is there a way to set that class attribute (`attribute1`) to some value, the same way that I can set my object instance attributes like this:

```
something = Something(value)
```

Comment: `Something.attribute1 = somevalue`?

Comment: Try use @classmethod

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992554/python-sharing-variables-between-different-instances-of-different-classes

Comment: Note that `_init_` should be `__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes just do

```
Something.attribute1 = "some value"
```

Class attributes can be accessed via the class name. You can do this inside any function defined in the class or even outside of it.