# Can I use python 2 and python3 in the same system?

Tags: python

It's a big project, some libraries are written in Python2 and some libraries are written in Python3. The project is big.

Is it possible to use both Python 2 and Python 3 in the same project?

Comment: Yes. Same as you can use any two or more languages in one project.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, but in one virtual environment, there is can only one version of Python. Right?

Comment: If you're using say Anaconda to run your virtualenvs , you may run into some issues since I don't think Anaconda natively supports multiple environment instances simultaeously. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953575/can-you-activate-multiple-python-virtual-environments-at-once for other solutions to work around this

Comment: there is no rule like that, indeed in your IDE you will have option to choose between the interpreter u want to use

Comment: @DerekG that Q talks abt simultaneous running, but in this Q OP only mentions about at the same system, nothing abt running both together

Comment: and about running the code, if your code contains mixed syntax's from python3 and 2 then it depends upon, which version runs the code and you can also use `try` and `except` to battle most of those error due to version change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install Python 3.x and 2.x on the same Windows computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341184/can-i-install-python-3-x-and-2-x-on-the-same-windows-computer)

Comment: Maybe [Sharing variables between different instances of different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992554)

Comment: It is very much possible to seemingly run both Py2 and Py3 code in one application — e.g. [cpy2py](https://github.com/maxfischer2781/cpy2py) (disclaimer: I maintained this package) uses a mechanism similar to multiprocessing but with different interpreters, and there are other means to do similar things. However, not only will this produce artifacts (e.g. copies instead of references) — Py2 and Py3 are subtly but fundamentally different and cannot be translated 1:1 unambiguously. In the general case, you still have to solve all the problems of porting the code from one version to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the structure of your project, it MAY be possible to do so. If the entire project must run from a single Python interpreter, using multiple versions of python will not be possible. However, it would be possible to run multiple python interpreters simultaneously, using sockets or some other inter-process communication tool to communicate between them. Without more information on your project, it's hard to tell to what extent this might be feasible.

Comment: For example, what other inter-process communication tool? Is there sockets example for this purpose?

Comment: I'd guess you'd have to use a socket-based protocol for this, or else write to shared file locations. For instance, MQTT provides lightweight UDP and TCP implementations for cross-process (cross interpreter) interfacing, which should work across python versions

Answer (score 0):

you can get two different window for the two python interpreters. For example, if you download **python 2.7** and what ever **python 3 version**, you can open the windows side-by-side.

Comment: Can you elaborate it on the details?